# python dblquad invalid callable

Tags: python, scipy, integral

I am trying to approximate  the Gauss Linking integral for two straight lines in R^3 using dblquad. I've created this pair of lines as an object.

I have a form for the integrand in parametrisation variables s and t generated by a function `gaussint(self,s,t)` and this is working. I'm then just trying to define a function which returns the double integral over the two intervals [0,1].

Edit - the code for the function looks like this:

```
def gaussint(self,s,t):
        formnum = self.newlens()[0]*self.newlens()[1]*np.sin(test.angle())*np.cos(test.angle())
        formdenone = (np.cos(test.angle())**2)*(t*(self.newlens()[0]) - s*(self.newlens()[1]) + self.adists()[0] - self.adists()[1])**2
        formdentwo = (np.sin(test.angle())**2)*(t*(self.newlens()[0]) + s*(self.newlens()[1]) + self.adists()[0] + self.adists()[1])**2
        fullden = (4 + formdenone + formdentwo)**(3/2)
        fullform = formnum/fullden

        return fullform
```

The various other function calls here are just bits of linear algebra - lengths of lines, angle between them and so forth. s and t have been defined as symbols upstream, if they need to be.

The code for the integration then just looks like this (I've separated it out just to try and work out what was going on:

```
def approxint(self, s, t):
        from scipy.integrate import dblquad
        return dblquad(self.gaussint(s,t),0,1, lambda t:0,lambda t:1)
```

Running it gets me a lengthy bit of somewhat impenetrable process messages, followed by

```
ValueError: invalid callable given
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: The first parameter must be a function.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the first parameter is a function - the one generated by gaussint. Why would it not be?

Comment: Please include the code for `self.gaussint(s,t)`.

Comment: I have done in the edit

Comment: As far as I can tell, `self.gaussint(s,t)` returns a number, not a function. But the first parameter of `dblquad` must be a function.

Comment: No, I've checked, the output is {8.0*(0.5*(-4.0*s + 4.0*t)**2 + 0.5*(4.0*s + 4.0*t - 2.0)**2 + 4)**(-1.5)}